# Unknown provider: $angularFileUploadProvider <- $angularFileUpload in jasmine angular test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a directive on my angular module that I'm trying to write a test for.  First off, I'm not clear how to even test this directive properly, but at this point, I'm getting the following error when karma runs the test.

```
Unknown provider: $angularFileUploadProvider <- $angularFileUpload
```

Here's my test.

```
describe('Testing onlyDigits directive', function(){

    var elm, scope;

    beforeEach(module('jobBoard'))

    beforeEach(inject(function($route, $filter, $angularFileUpload, $animate, $rootScope, $compile) {
        elm = angular.element('<input id="testinput" type="number" onlyDigits />');
        scope = $rootScope;
        $compile(elm)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should limit input to numbers and decimal', function(){

    })
})
```

And here's my module with the directive...

```
angular.module('jobBoard', ['ngRoute', 'jobFilters', 'angularFileUpload','ngAnimate'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider','$sceDelegateProvider', 'templates', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $sceDelegateProvider, templates){
        //routes ommitted for brevity
    }
]).directive('onlyDigits', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) return;
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (inputValue) {
                var digits = inputValue.split('').filter(function (s) { return (!isNaN(s) && s != ' ' || s == '.'); }).join('');
                ngModel.$viewValue = digits;
                ngModel.$render();
                return digits;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and here's my karma config file

```
module.exports = function(config){
  config.set({

    basePath : './',

    files : [
      'vendor/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js',
      'vendor/assets/javascripts/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'vendor/assets/javascripts/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'vendor/assets/javascripts/ng-file-upload-shim/angular-file-upload.js',
      'vendor/assets/javascripts/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload.js',
      'vendor/assets/javascripts/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/assets/javascripts/components/**/*.js',
      'app/assets/javascripts/view*/**/*.js',
      'spec/javascripts/**/*_spec.js'
    ],

    autoWatch : true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers : ['Chrome'],

    plugins : [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-junit-reporter'
            ],

    junitReporter : {
      outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
      suite: 'unit'
    }

  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are injecting alot of services in your jasmine `beforeEach` setup:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($route, $filter, $angularFileUpload, $animate, $rootScope, $compile) {
    // ...
}
```

You should only inject the services, that you are actually using in the `beforeEach` function: `$rootScope` and `$compile`:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    // ...
});
```

In particular the `$angularFileUpload` service, that you are trying to inject is not defined in any of the modules loaded: `'jobBoard'` and `['ngRoute', 'jobFilters', 'angularFileUpload','ngAnimate']`

Comment: That's what I'm trying to wrap my head around with angular.  So, even if the module is expecting all of these - 'ngRoute', 'jobFilters', 'angularFileUpload','ngAnimate' - you're saying I don't need to inject them?

Comment: The module is defining its module dependencies in the module definition: `angular.module("MyModule", ["OtherModule", "OtherModule2"])`
When the module is loaded in the test `beforeEach(function () { module("MyModule");})`, it automatically loads it's dependencies.
The things you inject are not _modules_, but _services_.
You only inject stuff if you need to use that particular service in your function: `inject(function ($http) { $http.get(...); })`.
Hope that helps :-)

Comment: It does help - somewhat;)  But when I reduce the services to only $compile and $rootScope, I then get this error - Unknown provider: $$jqLiteProvider <- $$jqLite <- $animate <- $compile

Comment: The `$$jqLiteProvider` (providing the `$$jqLite` service) is defined here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.14/src/jqLite.js#L1009
And the `$animate` service injects `$$jqLite` here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.14/src/ngAnimate/animate.js#L478

Comment: Does that mean I'm changing my inject to inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $$jqLite)) ?  I've tried that and still get the same error.

Comment: No, you should only inject the services you need in your injected function, the depency chain: `$$jqLite` <- `$animate` <- `$compile` is defined in the `ng` module. I'm not sure why the the `$$jqLite` service is not resolved when initializing `$animate`. What angular version are you using?

Comment: It seems like you have hit this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10435
Mixed versions of `angular.js` and `angular-animate.js`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  I checked both files and they are both v1.3.14:(

Comment: Do you by any chance have an angular file or some angular code anywhere else in your file tree? In `app/assets/javascripts/components/**/*.js`, maybe?

Comment: I have recreated your setup as described here: https://github.com/homburg/karma-angular-1.3.14 I can't seem to reproduce the error. Try comparing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  My project exists alongside 2 other projects within one rails solution.  There was another karma configuration file that was loading different versions of angular and angular animate.  Updating the angular file to what all the others used solved the problem.  Thanks again!